Assumption in proof of one-dimensional Alexandrov spaces are manifolds
My question is about the proof of theorem 15.18 in Alexandrov Geometry: Foundations of Alexander, Kapovitch, Petrunin.
The theorem is stated as follow:

15.18. Theorem. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a one-dimensional complete length $CBB(\kappa)$ space. Then $\mathcal{L}$ is isometric to a connected complete Riemannian one-dimensional manifold with possibly nonempty boundary. 
Proof. [...] 
Now we assume that no geodesic includes $p$ as a nonendpoint.
Since $\operatorname{LinDim}\mathcal{L}=1$, there is a point $y\neq p$.
Fix a positive value $\varepsilon<|p-y|$.
Let us show $B(p,\varepsilon)\subset[py]$; in particular $B(p,\varepsilon)=[0,\varepsilon)$.
Assume the contrary; let $z\in B(p,\varepsilon)\setminus [py]$.
Choose a point $w\in ]py[$ such that
$$ |p-w| + |p-z| < \varepsilon. $$
Consider geodesic $[wz]$, and let $q\in [py]\cap [wz]$ be the point that maximizes the distance $|w-q|$.
Since no geodesic includes $p$ as a nonendpoint, we have $p\neq q$. As above, $\measuredangle[q^p_y]=\pi$ and $\uparrow_{[qz]}$ is distinct from $\uparrow_{[qp]}$ and $\uparrow_{[qy]}$.
Thus, according to Proposition 15.7, $\operatorname{LinDim}\mathcal{L}>1$, a contradiction.

My question is about the assumption $|p-w| + |p-z| < \varepsilon$ when we choose $w$.
I have no clue how this can be useful in the proof.
